# Basic reverse function

Tags: beginner, clojure

I am just starting out in my Clojure journey and I wonder if anybody can point out my beginners mistakes in my function below that simply reverses a list.  I know that there is already a reverse function so this is purely for learning.

```
(defn rev
  ([l]
   (if (= (count l) 1) l (rev '() l)))
  ([l orig]
   (if (= (count orig) 0)
     l
     (rev (conj l (first orig)) (rest orig)))))
```

In my defence, it does work, but what I am finding myself doing a lot in Clojure is overloading the arguments list to take into account when I need a working list like in this example where I `conj` new items onto.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes using arity overloading like you've done is the best way to write a function.

I tried to rewrite your function using destructuring, like this:

```
(defn rev [[x & more]]
  (if more
    ...
```

however, it doesn't really work because you need some way of storing your "result sequence" in progress, which in your function is `l`. Because we're trying to write a reverse function, it's hard to do what we want without having some way of "building up" the sequence as we go and storing it in an intermediate value.

Taking a look at [how reverse is actually implemented in Clojure](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L906), we can see that a more concise way to express this idea of iterating over a sequence and building up a result sequence is by using `reduce` with a starting value of `'()`:

```
(defn reverse [coll]
  (reduce conj '() coll))
```

The magic behind this is that we're starting with a seq, `'()`. When you `conj` something onto a seq, it adds it to the beginning, not the end. So what this does is it starts with an empty seq, then goes through the input list items one by one and adds them to the beginning of the result list, so that you end up with a list that's reversed.

EDIT: Leonid has a more thorough answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22744672/2338327).

Answer (score 2):

- The 2 argument version of your function ought not to be exposed. Define
  it with a `let` or `letfn` form instead.
- You say you are reversing a list. Wherever you call for a list, a
  lazy sequence can turn up. Then `count` runs right to the end of the
  sequence *every time*. SLOW, for sequences of any length. So use
  `empty?` instead.
- You deal with case `1` of length separately. There is no need to.
- (More advanced) You are using explicit recursion: consuming one stack
  frame for every element in the original sequence. This sets a fairly 
  low limit on the length of the list you can deal with: probably
  around the 10K mark (YMMV). Luckily, the recursive call to `rev` is
  the last thing that happens: you can replace it with `recur`.
- And - trivially - you don't need to quote `()`.

Those who don't want to see the outcome should look away now.

```
(defn rev [l] 
  (letfn [(rev2 [l orig]
          (if (empty? orig)
            l
            (recur (conj l (first orig)) (rest orig))))]
    (rev2 () l)))
```

This is pretty well what you get using the standard `reverse`: though it's much more concisely expressed using `reduce`.

Comment: I've just looked at [Leonid's answer elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22744672/1562315) referred to by Dave Yarwood. He's not bothered about exposing `(rev [x y])`. Apart from that, there's little more to learn from my answer. And he's shown you the `(if-let [[x & xs] (seq s)] ... )` trick.